# Potentially uninitialized local variable used? Why?

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, initialization

When I write this code and compile with `/W4`

```
long r;
__try { r = 0; }
__finally { }
return r;
```

I get:

```
warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'r' used
```

Why does this happen?

**Edit (in 2024):** This [only happens in 32-bit mode, not 64-bit mode](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAEx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApJIBCZ86SX1kBPAMqN0AYVS0AriwZ6XAGTwGTAA5bwAjTGIQAHZSAAdUBUJHBncvHz1E5IcBQOCwlkjouNtMe1ShAiZiAnTvXy4bTDtchiqagnzQiKjYm2ra%2BsymhUGuoJ6ivpiAShtUT2Jkdg4gggBqFiYgiFmNkxjLDQBBDfON2gFgDeITAGZjs4uAfReCYgBPA6Pbg/uACIbDQPcw/AEmU4XDZvGjMWi0b6HMGHCFQi7ETAEJYMW6gyEnVEEjjzWicACsvF8HC0pFQnFcVisGwUi2WmAOknuPFIBE0JPmAGsQPd7gA6UWSqXSgBs%2Bk4ABYqfy6ZxeAoQBpefz5nBYDBEChUCx4nQouRKGgTWbogA3ZDxeIvW1cACcL3uAA4XqpPXKaLQCFENRBwirwkEap9ODyI8wvgB5cLacp87i8K1sQQJhiIlVYcKeYCuMS0DXp0hYbZGcQ03j4TEVW2Ycu0zCqcqeIMx3jrFoq2h4cLEKPuLAqj54Fg9%2BZUAzABQANTwmAA7gn4owezJBCIxOwpDv5Eo1CrdE0DEYUEyLPohxrIPNUPE2uWAPQAdQVGzfCckvFQZtiGIPAsAfPZmlaVJnAYNwPAaPxYO6QpiiyJIUgEYZGgSdC2mQ3polGFpU0qcYsL0MoKgEDpanw6ZCIGTpyNGcY6NQrh5lZJYVgkUkKWVOtVQ4DZfRlLYFHtDYXVdCVPQ2CBcEIEhOW5WZeDTLRZiFEByS1MkOCVUhpxlGSNFdDRyUkDQNCs8luRie5SGpWl6Q4dVNW1OtdQNCAkEWAh4i7C0ICtU16GIEJWFWUTxMk6TZN4TB8CIED0D0fhd1EcRDwy48VHUQTz1IVcR3iGd5Q4SknJVVyEy7QLNlQKgRL9WLkCkt1ZPk9xrXClSOPUnV5gQTAmCwaIIP0wzp3uDQxXM10FRiV1XWWhUZU9SQ4mcgC1RsDyNIFUhhVFCVpXO0U5X0%2B4BJcvbDu8%2BA9UNUKbWC17wpAe1HWdN0PW9VQZQVPg6CDYgQzDQS4yjbdocTZNU23TNGAIHM80EgsixLBFyx5KtDGAWtaQbEjm1bRKO2QLtVh5Pt9NpQdh1HDBVlpSdp3TWd5yXFd103akeVyvdsukXLFHys8QGkS9jBvaxGfAp8X1Sd8vx/P8AKA1KW3gTjiKo3wIBcZjSACSYUL6JpsgwtJ4JGHCclSNjLcgkjqLIu3sMotoaImAoCIoj2Mi91jzYDjiFm4g8%2BMq27duEwHvxYCT2vir15MUlL%2BrUzzNO006LouirppADb5t0mVyU9KQNC4GJJC4YGdqE9ytQe0hnt8kB/Ia97jTCqJIrYThE7ajqZK9RLkpIUD0tkYWD1F2RxdPQqpeK0ryv0qrm9q%2Bquw2JqRKBse07kiAeoH4gVMkHOHuG0bxsoGOS%2B5MUNAVV17gVLhPWWzaYh%2BibjVPaGo25DWOiKcUhdzoVRutVQSrlBpeRjv%2BBBd03K5yOkBZITgFRAA%3D%3D%3D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't be sure the code inside of the try block will successfully run. In this case it always will, but if there's additional code in the try block r = 0 may never execute. In that case r is uninitialized hence the error.

It's no different than if you said:

```
long r;
if(something) {
  r = 0;
}
return r;
```

(where 'something' is pretty much anything other than a constant true value).

Comment: If `r = 0` doesn't execute then wouldn't an exception be raised?

Comment: Possibly, but the point is you are using a variable that the compiler can't 100% determine will be initialized so it gives you an error. The try block adds ambiguity about whether or not r will be initialized. As a human it's easy to determine r will be initialized, but your computer is not a human.

Comment: If there was an `__except` ("catch") block, I would understand, since the variable would remain uninitialized through the catch block... but I don't really understand why this is happening here, since AFAIK it's impossible for the variable to remain uninitialized.

Comment: Most likely it's a limitation of the compiler and engine. For example in most cases writing: long r; boolean t = true; if(t) { r = 0;} return r; will result in the same error because the compiler is just checking the code not logically analyzing it.

Comment: Hmm okay... not the answer I was looking for but probably correct. +1 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer as it is of more interest than in just a comment:
The error never appeared until a *labeled-statement*: was inserted before the variable. Remove the `goto` & associated label and there is no warning.
This might have something to do with how namespace pathing is setup with a similar warning [C4702](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c26da40e.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) generated on a line number *before* the insertion of a `goto` block. MVCE still to be generated if anyone is interested.

Comment: Yes this is a very valid reason, just fixed it because of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because `long r;` creates `r` but it is not initialized; it is null.

So it warns you that the variable is not initialized.  In certain cases it will cause Null Pointers.