# #ERROR# potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'ptrNames' used

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl

I get the error "potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'ptrNames' used" if I run this code:

```
void processHits (GLint hits, GLuint buffer[]) //Some prints
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    GLuint names, *ptr, minZ,*ptrNames, numberOfNames;
    if (hits == 0)
        noSelected = true;
    else 
        noSelected = false;
    ptr = (GLuint *) buffer;
    minZ = 0xffffffff;
    for (i = 0; i < hits; i++) {
        names = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        if (*ptr < minZ) {
            numberOfNames = names;                                                   
            minZ = *ptr;
            ptrNames = ptr+2;
        }
        ptr += names+2;
    }
    ptr = ptrNames; //Error at this line!
    for (j = 0; j < numberOfNames; j++,ptr++) {
        if (hits > 0)
           LastSelected = *ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show at least *some* effort. What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284782/potentially-uninitialized-local-variable-used-why

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is correct.  `ptrNames` is only initialised if the test `if (*ptr < minZ)` succeeds.

The easiest fix may be to initialise `ptrNames` to `NULL` then check its value after the first `for` loop, returning (since there are no hits to process) if it hasn't been updated.

```
void processHits (GLint hits, GLuint buffer[]) //Some prints
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    GLuint names, *ptr, minZ,*ptrNames=NULL, numberOfNames;
    ...
    if (ptrNames == NULL)
        return;
    ptr = ptrNames;
    ...
}
```

Comment: in the latter case `ptrNames` will still be uninitialized when the assignment occurs. It's outside the for loop, which might not be easily visible due to the bad formatting.

Comment: @ArneMertz Thanks.  I've updated the formatting in the question to make this clearer.  I'll update my answer in a sec...

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `ptrNames` variable to something. The `if (*ptr < minZ)` may prevent `ptrNames` to be set to something therefor you will a pointer that points somewhere you don't know and potentially break everything.